# Best way to deploy EXE shared among several applications

Tags: .net, deployment

I have applications A and B both of which make use of a shared component S. If S were a DLL assembly, I would just put a copy of it to each application as a private assembly. But S is an EXE, and A and B talk to it through a protocol. When A and B are running, they must talk to the same instance of S. Possible scenarios:

1. The user installs A and S is installed together with it because A depends on S. Later the user installs B, but S is not installed because it's already there.
2. The user installs A and S is installed together with it. Later the user installs B which comes with a newer version of S. S is replaced with the new version.
3. A and B are installed (and S). The user uninstalls B, but S is kept because A is still there. Later the user uninstalls A and S is uninstalled too because no application depends on it anymore.

New versions of S will be compatible with older versions of A and B. E. g. if the protocol changes, S will support both old and new protocol etc.

What will be the best deployment strategy in this case? I'm using Windows Installer (MSI). It seems it's good to have S as a separate application with a separate MSI and invoke that MSI from other MSIs, but maybe there are better approaches. Maybe MSM?.. I'd like to keep installation simple. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSI uses reference counting to take care of your exact scenario.  A unique item (location and binary) should be assigned a component GUID and then have that component GUID shared across MSIs.  This can easily be done if you use WiX via a common Fragment that is compiled into both MSIs (A & B).  Then when you install A & B, regardless of order, the ref count of S will be incremented and thus an uninstall of one won't remove the exe if the other has installed it as well.

The key is to make sure that both the MSIs use the same component GUID and install S to the same location.

EDIT - Adding a URL on component ref counting from MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that the attribute is called msidbComponentAttributesSharedDllRefCount but it should work for your scenario I believe.

Comment: Nick, thanks for pointing me to WiX. The solution you proposed looks promising, but wouldn't it be even better to have S in an MSM and merge it via a common fragment? This would ensure the GUID and the path of S were the same for both A and B. What is your opinion?

Comment: Also I've searched for msidbComponentAttributesSharedDllRefCount and found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/08/30/458295.aspx. In the comment of "1 Sep 2005 2:30 AM" Aaron Stebner says "Windows Installer also keeps an internal ref count for component IDs of all components that are installed on the system, regardless of whether or not it installs the files contained in those components, and regardless of what the component attribute settings are in the Component table of your MSI.", so maybe I don't need to set msidbComponentAttributesSharedDllRefCount?

Comment: To answer both your questions, I think a) Yes an MSM makes sense in this case for portability and reuse and b) the article does indeed seem to indicate that you don't need to set the attribute.